# Exclude most recent entry type from a loop

Tags: entry, exclude

Hey everyone I am trying to output entries on the homepage. My goal is that the most recent entry is styled differently.
I achieved this by calling the loop too times:
    `{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blogPosts').limit(1) %}`
than
   `{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blogPosts').all() %}`
and it works perfectly.
My only issue is that I want to exclude the most recent post from the second loop, so it only appear in the first loop.

Is there a way in craft for exactly the most recent entry or I should do this with ID?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice is to only query for the data once, then perform any necessary filtering on the result, rather than making multiple expensive calls to `craft.entries...`

So in your case you could take the first entry using `[0]`, and then use Craft's `without` filter to filter out the first entry from the list:

```
{% set posts = craft.entries.section('blogPosts').all() %}
{% set firstPost = posts[0] %}
{% set otherPosts = posts|without(firstPost) %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish this, is by adding an offset of 1.

Result:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blogPosts').offset(1).all() %}
```

You can find it in the documentation [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#offset).

---

Also, instead of getting all the entries and limiting it to 1, you can use `.first()`

```
craft.entries.section('blogPosts').first()
```